# Problemas no uso do PDO

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu tinha o costume de utilizar MySQLi, porém agora passei a utilizar o PDO. 
Estou tendo um pouco de dificuldades nesse início.

Fiz o código abaixo, só que quando utilizo a condicional e ele entra no `else`, não é retornado algo para o retorno do AJAX. Eu dou um `console.log`, no retorno do AJAX e sai nada.

O `echo` sai no arquivo do PHP, porém não é retornado.

Vocês poderiam me ajudar e dizer onde posso estar errando ?

**Código:**

```js
function pesquisarDetalhesClientes(dados, cod_line, depart_line) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      botao: dados,
      cod: cod_line,
      depart_ativ: depart_line
    },
    url: "../banco/banco-vision/pagina-controle-de-tarefas/interface-consulta-comentarios-cliente.php",
    cache: false,
    async: false

  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    let detalhes = "";

    //Aqui abaixo, preenchemos as divs com os dados vindo da consulta ao arquivo php do AJAX]
    if (data != "naotemresponsavelnaempresa") {
      if (data.detalhes_cliente == null) {
        info = "Não Possui Observações";
        detalhes = "<p>" + info + "</p>";
      } else {
        detalhes = "<p>" + data.detalhes_cliente + "</p>";
      }
    } else {
      //$("#enviar-modal-observacoes-cliente").prop('disabled',true);       
      alert("Sem responsavel");
    }




    //Função para preencher a <div> com os <p> e manter o scroll embaixo
    /*
    $("#espaco-dialogo-atividades").html(detalhes).promise().then(function(){
        $("#espaco-dialogo-atividades").animate({ scrollTop: $("#espaco-dialogo-atividades").prop("scrollHeight") }, 0);
    });
    */

    $("#espaco-dialogo-atividades-cliente").html(detalhes);

  }).fail(function() {

  }).always(function() {

  });
}
```

```php
<?php

        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

        // CONEXAO
        session_start();
        $banco = $_SESSION['banco'];
        $bancodedados = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$banco";
        $usuario_banco = 'jcasiste_marco';
        $senha = 'Arg@tsi@123';

        //CONSULTA NO BANCO QUE PREENCHE A ÁREA DE DETALHE E FEEDBACK NA PARTE DE BAIXO DA TELA INTERFACE.PHP
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

        if(is_string($_SESSION["nome"]))
        {
            $usuario = $_SESSION["nome"];           
        }
        else
        {
            die("A SESSION[nome] não tem caracter String");
            exit;           
        }   

        try
        {

        $conexao = new PDO($bancodedados,$usuario_banco,$senha,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

        //$usuario = $_SESSION["nome"];
        $codigo_detalhes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'botao', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $cod_detalhes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cod', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $departamento_detalhes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'depart_ativ', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


        //COMENTAR ISSO AQUI
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios_connect WHERE COD = ? and departamento = ?";

        $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$cod_detalhes);
        $stmt->bindValue(2,$departamento_detalhes);
        $stmt->execute();

        $count_responsaveis_no_cliente = $stmt->rowCount();

        //$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

            if($count_responsaveis_no_cliente > 0)
            {           
                $query = "SELECT detalhes_cliente FROM tbl_atividades WHERE codigo = ?";

                $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bindValue(1,$codigo_detalhes);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                echo json_encode($result);              
            }
            else
            {
                echo "naotemresponsavelnaempresa";              
            }   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            //Verificando o erro ocorrido
            echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();         
        }                               

?>
```

Comment: Já pensou em retornar um JSON válido ao invés da *string* `"naotemresponsavelnaempresa"`? E veja se por acaso não está sendo executado a função `fail` no seu JS. Você não tratou essa função, então se ela é executada você não saberá.

Comment: Tem problema em mandar assim ? E o que seria um sjon válido ?

Comment: Se o JS espera um JSON e você não enviar um ele executará o `fail` ao invés do `done`.

Comment: Mas o JS espera realmente um JSON ?

Comment: Sim, você disse no PHP que estará enviando um JSON ao definir o cabeçalho `Content-type: application/json`. O JS verá que é um JSON e tentará tratar o corpo da resposta como tal, dando erro por não ser um JSON válido.

Comment: Segue as dicas do Mestre Anderson, porque podem ser esses erros mesmo, para ver o que pode estar acontecendo, coloca um `.fail(function(a,b){console.log(a);console.log(b);}` que pode ajudar

Comment: Vou seguir as dicas sim.

Comment: Estava acontecendo exatamente isso, @AndersonCarlosWoss . Então eu tirei a String e passei a retornar um JSON. Realmente estava entrando no FAIL. Obrigado pela ajuda, brother. Vou atualizar a pergunta e mostrar como ficou o código. Se quiser criar uma resposta, eu aceito pra vc.

Comment: @Petherson Não edite a pergunta apenas para adicionar a solução. Se é solução deveria estar nas respostas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No PHP você está enviando o seguinte cabeçalho na resposta HTTP:

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Isso fará com que o jQuery entenda que a resposta seja um JSON e tentará analisar o corpo da resposta como tal. O problema é que no PHP as mensagens de erros são *string* cruas, como texto sem formatação.

```
die("A SESSION[nome] não tem caracter String");
echo "naotemresponsavelnaempresa";
echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();
```

Se qualquer uma dessas três linhas forem executadas a sua resposta HTTP será algo como:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

naotemresponsavelnaempresa
```

Isso fará com que no JavaScript, quando o jQuery tentar analisar o corpo da resposta, faça `JSON.parse("naotemresponsavelnaempresa")`.

```js
const resultado = JSON.parse("naotemresponsavelnaempresa")

console.log(resultado)
```

Dará erro porque o valor não é um JSON válido. Assim, ao dar erro, ao invés de executar o *callback* `done` será executado o `fail`.

Cabe a você decidir se quer alterar o PHP para sempre retornar um JSON válido ou se alterará o JS para lidar também com erros.

Answer (score 2):

Após seguir as dicas do Anderson, fiz o código da maneira certa. 
**Segue abaixo como ficou:**

```js
function pesquisarDetalhesClientes(dados, cod_line, depart_line) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      botao: dados,
      cod: cod_line,
      depart_ativ: depart_line
    },
    url: "../banco/banco-vision/pagina-controle-de-tarefas/interface-consulta-comentarios-cliente.php",
    cache: false



  }).done(function(data) {

    let detalhes = "";

    //Aqui abaixo, preenchemos as divs com os dados vindo da consulta ao arquivo php do AJAX]

    if (data.count != 0) {
      if (data.preencher.detalhes_cliente == null) {

        info = "Não Possui Observações";
        detalhes = "<p>" + info + "</p>";
      } else {
        detalhes = "<p>" + data.preencher.detalhes_cliente + "</p>";
      }
    } else {

      $("#enviar-modal-observacoes-cliente").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#div-botao-enviar-mensagem-cliente").prepend("<span class='text-danger font-weight-bold'>Cliente não possui correspondente no departamento <span class='text-dark'>" + data.preencher.departamento + "</span> cadastrado no Connect!</span>");
    }

    $("#espaco-dialogo-atividades-cliente").html(detalhes);

  }).fail(function() {
    alert("Erro na consulta: Verifique com o T.I");
  }).always(function() {

  });
}
```

```html
<?php
    
  header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        
  // CONEXAO
  session_start();
  $banco = $_SESSION['banco'];
  $bancodedados = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$banco";
  $usuario_banco = 'jcasiste_marco';
  $senha = 'Arg@tsi@123';
      
  //CONSULTA NO BANCO QUE PREENCHE A ÁREA DE DETALHE E FEEDBACK NA PARTE DE BAIXO DA TELA INTERFACE.PHP
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    
       
  try
  {
   
  $conexao = new PDO($bancodedados,$usuario_banco,$senha,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
   
  //$usuario = $_SESSION["nome"];
  $codigo_detalhes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'botao', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $cod_detalhes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cod', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $departamento_detalhes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'depart_ativ', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     
  
  //COMENTAR ISSO AQUI
  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios_connect WHERE COD = :cod_detalhes and departamento = :departamento_detalhes";
  $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindValue(':cod_detalhes',$cod_detalhes);
  $stmt->bindValue(':departamento_detalhes',$departamento_detalhes);
  $stmt->execute();
  
  $count_responsaveis_no_cliente = $stmt->rowCount();
   
  $query = "SELECT detalhes_cliente, departamento FROM tbl_atividades WHERE codigo = :codigo";
  
  $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindValue(":codigo",$codigo_detalhes);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  
   
  $json_resultado = array(
   'preencher' => $result,
   'count' => $count_responsaveis_no_cliente    
  );
  
  echo json_encode($json_resultado);   
  
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   //Verificando o erro ocorrido
   echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();   
  }        
    
?>
```